# Hide A Console C++ Program From Taskbar

Tags: c++, windows, taskbar

I have a little **console** game that calls another console app. Something like **Winamp**'s many windows (*main* and *playlist*). The thing is when I call two for example console windows the programs opened in the **taskbar** get too many, I don't need to open the windows separately, I want only the **main** window to stay in the taskbar and when I click on it, *it* and **all its child apps** to pop up.

P.S. I am familiar with `ShowWindow ( GetConsoleWindow(), SW_HIDE );`, but it hides the window as well and I want it to be hidden only from the taskbar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only way I am aware of to accomplish this on a console window is to use the shell interface [ITaskbarList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774652%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

```
hr = CoCreateInstance(
    CLSID_TaskbarList,
    NULL,
    CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
    IID_ITaskbarList,
    reinterpret_cast<void**>(&taskbar));
if(!FAILED(hr))
{
    // Remove the icon from the task bar
    taskbar->DeleteTab(GetConsoleWindow());
    // Release it
    taskbar->Release();
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Thanks to Captain Obvlious and some research, the following code:

```
ITaskbarList *pTaskList = NULL;
HRESULT initRet = CoInitialize(NULL);
HRESULT createRet = CoCreateInstance( CLSID_TaskbarList,
                                      NULL,
                                      CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
                                      IID_ITaskbarList,
                                      (LPVOID*)&pTaskList );

if(createRet == S_OK)
{

    pTaskList->DeleteTab(GetConsoleWindow());

    pTaskList->Release();
}

CoUninitialize();
```

with included `ShObjIdl.h` works great!

Note: You should get **S_OK** as a value in **initRet** and **createRet**!